# Google cache returns the mobile version of a question

Tags: support, mobile-web, google, caching

Sometimes I use google to access a cached version of a question on a Stack Exchange site. However, when I do so, it returns the mobile version of the site, which removes some information and therefore isn't as useful as I would like. The site isn't responsive, of course because it is cached and therefore, I can't just click the `full site` button at the bottom of the page.

**Is there any other way I can access a question cached by google while using the full site, or does google only cache the mobile version for some version?**

Comment: Why would you want a cached version of a question?

Comment: @Shadow9 In case I want to see a deleted question, so I know why it was deleted, or in case I want to see who a deleted user was before they deleted their account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is due to [mobile first indexing](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-cache-mobile-version-26619.html). I don’t believe that Google stores a second copy for you to access, but you may be able to find the information you want through [Archive.org](https://archive.org), the data dumps/SEDE, or by asking a more privileged user (depending on what exactly you’re looking for).